# What is RFH header in MQ messages and its purpose

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

When I am writing message in MQ queue through JMS, RFH header is also getting added with message as its property.

Property including

- Jms delivery Mode
- JMS Destination
- JMS Timestamp
- Mcd.msd

Can anyone explain me its use and significance?

Answer (score 2):

The RFH header only allow for a single header to exist in a message, and the RFH2 header allow multiples headers to exist in a message.

I'm not going to explain, this site explained it better than I can :

New Link (previous one was not working anymore)

https://docs.actian.com/dataconnect/11.4/index.html#page/User/RFH_Header_Support_3a_Websphere_MQ.htm

I hope it will help you !